# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always false in .net core custom authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Can anyone please check below code and let me know why I'm getting always false (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)??. I'm getting cookie on my browser properly and 
 able to get value from Claim but "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" always false.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string phoneNumber, int otp, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (this.accountService.ValidateOTP(phoneNumber, otp))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, phoneNumber),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, phoneNumber)
            };
            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            userIdentity.AddClaims(claim);
            ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance", userPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20),
                    IsPersistent = false,
                    AllowRefresh = false
                });

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Ad");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated` returns `false` when `ClaimsIdentity.AuthenticationType` is null or empty. To avoid that, stop using the parameterless `ClaimsIdentity` constructor and use the overload accepting an `authenticationType` parameter:

```
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) what is the use of parameterless constructor??

Comment: It is incredible that works like that ha ha, but indeed it works!

Answer (score 16):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but it might be useful to another person.

Using `app.UseAuthentication();` right before `app.UseAuthorization();` inside the Configure method in the Startup.cs class fixed it for me.

Answer (score 13):

In my case the problem was in the startup file. app.UseAuthentication() line was coming after app.UseMvc() line.I reversed the orders and it started to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. I think this can help

`var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity( claims, AuthenticationTypes.Basic);`

Answer (score 0):

Mine is .net core 6 app.

I also observed that

```
HttpContext.User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated
```

is always false.

For me selecting the correct overload of the [AddAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension method resolved the issue.

Choosing [the AddAuthentication overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-authenticationservicecollectionextensions-addauthentication(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-string)) in which I have to specify the default schema, sets IsAuthenticated flag appropriately.

```cs
var authBuilder = builder.Services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth");
```

Basically I am configuring a cookie Auth handler.

```cs
var authBuilder = builder.Services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth");
authBuilder.AddCookie("CookieAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuth";
});
```

If you want to take a look at the full example, [here it is](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/AspNetCoreSecurityTuts/tree/main/src/dotnet-apps/00310-WebAppCookieAuthContextPrep).

We have to specify which scheem we have to use. The schmeme name provides a logical grouping of the auth handler, identity and cliams principles all together. We have to tell the middleware, which scheme we are trying to use so that the middleware will be able to locate which auth service you are trying to use to do the authentication.

So basically by providing the scheme name in the following overload,

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth");
```

the middleware UseAuthentication will be able to know which handler to use. So then this handler will be able to deserialize the in coming cookie and set the IsAuthencated flag to true