# Failure in migrating asp.net core 1.x project with Jwt authentication to 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, migrate, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to migrate my asp.net core 1.1 project to asp.net core 2.0.
I've used the guidelines from [her](https://dev.to/samueleresca/developing-token-authentication-using-aspnet-core) to implement jwt authentication.

Now that I've upgraded to 2.0, I've used the guidelines in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x) to migrate, but HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.

The client correctly sends the bearer token.
Any links or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261732/user-identity-isauthenticated-always-false-in-net-core-custom-authentication

Comment: Running into the same problem. And it no longer returns `Unauthorized` but tries to redirect to a non-existent login page.

Comment: @user2771704 My problem is not that. We user the parametered constructor

Comment: @Knelis It's another symptom of the same problem. The user is not correctly authenticated

Comment: If you're using `.AddIdentity`, that actually sets some default parameters for authentication. What I did to get it working for JWT bearer only is override those settings like this: `services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; }).AddJwtBearer( ... );`